# Build webapi odata model dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

All of the webapi+odata examples I've seen so far build the model in `WebApiConfig.Register` using something like:

```
...
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<AClass>("SetName");
...
IEdmModel model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
```

In my case, I would like to dynamically build the classes used in `modelBuilder.EntitySet<AClass>("SetName")` at runtime and register them on the fly, the first time a request for this entity set is executed.

I've read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/leohu/archive/2013/11/05/typeless-entity-object-support-in-webapi.aspx)
where [EdmEntityObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.edmentityobject%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is used when no backing CLR type is available but the model is still built during the startup of the service.

Is there a way to build the model on the fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sample addresses your requirement quite well: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation/

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently reading this. I'm also trying to return strongly typed entities instead of edm collections. (+I don't know if it's just me but a doc could be handy...)

Comment: Does not work in Microsoft.AspNet.OData v6. Only 5.7.

Comment: Warning: The current sample works using Microsoft.AspNet.OData v7. Note that it currently ONLY works when self hosting instead of hosting in IIS. Url: [link](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiClassic/DynamicEdmModelCreation)